# responsive grid frameworks - float: vs display: table-cell

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

I've used Bootstrap, and researched Foundation. From what I've seen, both of them use `float:` to achieve responsive grids.

I've also seen responsive grids using only `display: table-cell` and `@media` queries.

The latter seems better to me because `float:` is intended to achieve a particular typographical effect, so using it to achieve responsive grid layout seems like a hack.

My question: is `float:` used by bootstrap, foundation and other responsive grids to get around the lack of proper `table-cell` support in older browsers? If there is another reason, I'd like to hear that too.

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can require Bootstrap to use stacking (`z-index`) instead of `float`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are roughly 3 ways to make grid systems: `float` `inline-block` `table-cell`

They all have PROs and CONs. Bootstrap probably uses `float` because, being a framework, it adapts easily to different scenarios.

A big limit of the `float` method is that you can't vertically align grid elements, and personally I prefer using the `inline-block` method.

However, the `inline-block` method brings a problem of **whitespace** (because the grid items become kind of words) which can be fixed in various ways, as extensively explained by Chris Coyier:

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

The biggest problem with the `table-cell` method is, in my opinion, that you can only place grid elements in **one row** because you can't push them on a new line via CSS. This means that for each row you need a new container element, and it becomes very inflexible for responsive designs.

Comment: To be precise, these 3 methods will be obsolete when the Flexbox will be supported by all browsers.

Comment: You can also check this answer for a grid with floats and equal margins between elements : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23352245/1811992 . Can't wait for flexbox because this can become very complicated.

Comment: To add on the topic of spaces between inline block elements: You should be minifying your HTML anyways, so why not just add everything in one line.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everything that gyo has written and would only add that I have found [Pure grids](http://purecss.io/grids/) (formerly YUI3 grid) to be an effective and cross-browser friendly application of the inline-block method. Interestingly, it also incorporates some of the aforementioned Flexible Box properties. However, a big win, if internationalization is a requirement, is that inline-block automatically reverses when dir="rtl" is set, unlike float-based layouts (not sure about table).