# Responsive thumbnail grid equal spacing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid-layout

I have a grid of thumbnails:

```
.thumbnail-container {
          border: 1px solid red;
          float: left;
          width: 25%; (depending on screen size)
}

.thumbnail {
          display: block;
          height: auto;
          width: 200px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          padding: 0px;
}
```

you get the idea...

[image: grid]

Sometimes there are 5 thumbs, sometimes 4, 3, 2... in the same row depending on the @media device screen width.

So as you can see in the picture, my problem is the horizontal spacing between the thumbnails. Since the width of each thumb-container is equal (25% in the picture) and thumbnails are centered, there is **double** spacing betwet 1st and 2nd, 2nd-3d, 3rd-4th. On the contrary, the 1st thumb has half of that space to the left, and the 4th has it to the right:

It's like this: 1(A)2(B)2(C)2(D)1

And I want it like this: 1(A)1(B)1(C)1(D)1

Any ideas of how to make the spacing the same?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made this responsive grid that does what you need using CSS.
It uses **media queries** and **nth-child()**.

The horizontal and vertical margins are equal.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/KrA6M/)**

It shows you can use calculation to position grid elements with equal margins between each other. The margin between elements and window is also the same.

Code for screens wider than 751px isn't written yet though but you get the idea. Here is the code :

*HTML :*

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="foto">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="foto">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="foto">3</div>
    </div>
    ... And so on ...
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    min-width:150px;
}
.wrap {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
.foto {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: gold;
    position:absolute;
}

#warning{display:none;}
@media screen and (min-width: 631px) {
    .wrap {
        width:20%;
        padding-bottom:25%;
    }
    .wrap:nth-child(4n+2), .wrap:nth-child(4n+3){

    }
    .wrap .foto {
        top:-75px;
        margin-top:100%;
        right:-30px;
    }
    .wrap:nth-child(4n+2){
        margin:0 5% 0 7.5%;
    }
    .wrap:nth-child(4n+3){
     margin-right:7.5%;
    }
    .wrap:nth-child(4n+2) .foto{
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-75px;
    }
    .wrap:nth-child(4n+3) .foto{
        right:50%;
        margin-right:-75px;
    }
    .wrap:nth-child(4n) .foto{
        left:-30px;
    }   
    #container{
        margin-top:-45px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 631px) {
    .wrap {
        width:25%;
        padding-bottom:33.3%;
    }
    .wrap:nth-child(3n+2){
        margin:0 12.5%;        
    }
    .wrap .foto {
        top:-75px;
        margin-top:100%;
        right:-37px;
    }
     .wrap:nth-child(3n+2) .foto{
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-75px;
    }
     .wrap:nth-child(3n) .foto{
        left:-37px;
    }
    #container{
        margin-top:-37px;
    }
}


@media screen and (min-width: 331px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    .wrap {
        width:33.3%;
        padding-bottom:50%;
        clear:left;
    }
    .wrap:nth-child(even) {
        float:right;
        clear:right;
    }
    .wrap .foto {
        top:-75px;
        margin-top:100%;
        right:-50px;
    }
    .wrap:nth-child(even) .foto {
        left:-50px;
    }
    .wrap:nth-child(4n+3) .foto, .wrap:nth-child(4n+4) .foto {
        bottom:-75px;
        margin-bottom:100%;
    }
    #container{
        margin-top:-25px;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 330px) {
    .wrap {
        width:50%;
        padding-bottom:100%;
        clear:left;
    }
    .wrap:nth-child(odd) .foto {
        right:-75px;
        bottom:0;
        bottom:-75px;
        margin-bottom:100%;
    }
    .wrap:nth-child(even) .foto {
        top:0px;
        right:-75px;
        top:-75px;
        margin-top:100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 751px) {
    #warning{
        color:#fff;
        display:block;
        position:fixed;
        width:100%;
        height:50%;
        top:25%;
        left:0;
        background:#000;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:30px;
}
```

Comment: nice presentation fiddle! What kind of cross-browser compatibility did you go for? (i.e. how far back in IE does it support :P)

Comment: @JosephMarikle the CSS will need some tweaking, I just tested with IE tester and there are some alignment issues in IE9 and IE8 doesn't seem to work but I never know if it is a jsfiddle problem or if it comes from my CSS....

Comment: wow, that is some crazy code right there. The fiddle seems to confirm it's exactly what I'm looking for... however, may I dare ask if you could achieve the same with less code (ie. not using nth-childs? - i never knew that existed btw)

Comment: @James Well, if you have a class/id for each  thumbnail, you can avoid the `nth-child` but it can get more complicated depending on how many thumbnails you have. How many do you have?

Comment: no... no unique ids, thumbs can be unlimited really (120 per page at least). I'm scracthing my head with this one.

Comment: @James then, you will need the `:nth-child()` selector. otherwise it won't be  possible to target the first/last of every row. But I am thinking, you don't need bottom/top margins do you? it would make much more simple.

Comment: that's correct @web-tiki the vertical margins aren't necessary, just the horizontal spacing, "much more simple" sounds good!

Comment: @James ok, wait a few minutes, I'll strip the code you don't need.

Comment: @James let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51630/discussion-between-web-tiki-and-james)

Comment: @James here is the version with no top/bottom margins. It still is pretty complicated... http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/KrA6M/8/ I'll be back tomorow, I can explain better in the chat.

Comment: Hey @web-tiki sorry I couln't answer yesterday. I saw the updated fiddle, looks great. I just want to make sure: is the :nth-child() reliable in browser compatibility terms? Thanks so much for all your support!